# How can I open data:image in browser from node-webkit app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, webkit, node-webkit

I am using Node-Webkit for making an image enhancement app. I have a download button clicking on  which executes the following.

```
        document.getElementById("download").onclick = function(){
            var c = Caman("canvas");
            if(file.type.replace("image/","")=="jpeg"){
                //save as jpeg
                c.save('jpeg');
            } else {
                //saves as png by default
                c.save();
            }   
        }
    }
```

This function is supposed to download the image if run in browser, but the download doesn't work in the Node-Webkit app.

So, I want to make it function to open the data:image in default browser so that I can save image from the browser, but I have no idea how to do that. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can try with something like toDataURL and open it with nwgui.Shell but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Node-Webkit has support for [node.js filesystem API](/home/alexander/solr-4.10.1/example/manuals-test) . So you can use [fs.writeFile](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback) method to save the file.
Or you can take a look at [node-webkit-fdialogs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-webkit-fdialogs) wich should simplify the task for you .

When you want to use a node library you just need to `require` it in your javascript as you would in node. Take a look at the example :

```
var fs = require("fs");
$('#saveButton').click(function() {
    var canvasImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").split(',')[1];
    var decodedImg = window.atob(canvasImage);
    var img = new Buffer(decodedImg, encoding='base64');

    fs.writeFile("output.png", img, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("The file was saved!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I am guessing that this method will save a file, but I want to make it work without having to save the image.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [canvas-to-image](https://github.com/kaxi1993/canvas-to-image), it works for both node-webkit and browser.